# how to match multiple times a word after a specific starting point (word) using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select all the `option1, option2` etc.. after a `fromHere` string, but I am ending up selecting only the last occurrence (`option4`)

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T3h9g8/2)

And here is the example

Regex: `/(?=fromHere(.+((option\d))))/g`

Text:

```
    Ok ignoring this whole line option1 ignore


    fromHere I want to match all option1 ignore option2 ignore option3 xxxx
 option4  but got only the last one (4)
```

I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/fromHere` to split string removing `"fromHere"` from resulting array, `Array.prototype.pop()` to get index `1` of array, `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/option\d/g` to match `"optionN"` in string.

```js
let str = `    Ok ignoring this whole line option1 ignore


    fromHere I want to match all option1 ignore option2 ignore option3 xxxx
 option4  but got only the last one (4)`;

let res = str.split(/fromHere/).pop().match(/option\d/g);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks @guest271314, but my goal was to highlight the text while the user is typing so I can't trim the string. What I found interesting here is if I exclude the lookahead operator, all the option(x) will be matched. It is not a grep behavior but instead anything else.

Comment: @JLCDev You can use the approach at Answer to highlight the matches. Simply concatenate `res[0]` with `res[1]` joined by `" fromHere "`. Note that "my goal was to highlight the text while the user is typing" does not appear at original Question